# Can't get SQL Server CE toolbox to work in Visual Studio 13

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I've got a new instance of VS2013 and I'm trying to set up a SQL Server CE instance to test against.
I can't seem to even get started. I've installed the SQL Server CE Toolbox plugin, and when I open it all I get is a message that says

> The database has been created by an earlier version of SQL Server Compact. Please upgrade using SqlCeEngine.Upgrade() method

What database?

If I try and "Remove Broken Connections" I get a dialog with the same error message.
If I try and connect to an existing `Northwind.sdf` test connection works but when I say "OK" I get a dialog that says "Please tell ErikEJ about this problem"

Comment: Why not tell me, then? https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename/delete the files named SqlCe35AddinStore.sdf and SqlCe40AddinStore.sdf located in C:\Users\your name\AppData\Local (%appdata%).

Also make sure you have either SqlCe 4.0 or 3.5 properly installed.

The issue here was that the 3.5 installtion was broken, I will also attempt to improve the check for the precense of 3.5

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I've deleted SqlCe35AddinStore.sdf I don't see any 4.0 version. But still no luck.

Comment: In an effort to continue I created a 4.0 sdf in VS2012 and it then reopened in VS2013, the DB works, and your tools detect file version says 4.0 so I assume SqlCe is installed correctly. Any further help is appreciated. PS I sent an error report this time :-)

Comment: I have contacted you via mail, suggest we continue this conversation on the codeplex site, as this is reallly not a programming question